# How can I enable the user to enter reserved characters into the database with a combination of PHP, MySQL and AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, regex, ajax

I've set up a website that allows the user to add places to a database. However, I am unfamiliar with regex and so I'm not sure how to allow characters like apostrophes and dollar signs without them affecting the database INSERT.

I have a form, which is read by AJAX and processed with PHP/MySQL so there's thee languages which have their own "reserved" characters for various uses. Realistically the regex needs to sit in my Javascript before the AJAX sends the string. I'm quite new to Javascript so I'm not sure how I'd go about this.

Is there any chance someone could help with this, but also explain how this regex works?

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically when you dealing with user-submitted data you cannot be aware enough. Imo putting the regex check into the JavaScript area is a bad idea or not enough. You should be sure about you filter these kind of data everywhere (and sufficiently).

Common filtering rules that apply:

- Control user input as much as you can (predefined variables, auto-suggest, etc.)
- Filter out any unwanted input like html/script tags with [strip_tags](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).
- Use prepared statements or try to be familiar with [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for example
- At least use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before inserting to your database

Comment: I used mysql_real_escape string and it provided just the solution I needed. Cheers mate. I'll watch out for the injection though

Answer (score 0):

You definitely shouldn't be doing this client-side in Javascript, anything client-side is subject to tampering and opens up an enormous [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) security hole, which presumably you're familiar with if you're asking this question.

As far as I'm aware, the content of the string won't affect Javascript or PHP as it's, well, a string. It needs to be escaped before insertion into the database, have a look at the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. This is the solution I was looking for. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

No need to dabble in regex. Do the verification in the last possible step, here PHP, and use prepared statements in a well known and tested database library. Prepared statements will take care of properly quoting anything you throw at them.

A good example is [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-execute.php)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you want to use prepared statements for the PHP/SQL portion. With PDO:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO users SET username = :user');
    $stmt->bindParam(':user',$_POST['user']);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount == 1) {
        //success
    } else {
        //fail
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) { //Unhandled may expose $user/$password
    echo 'Database connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

and `$_POST['user']` could be `test'; DROP TABLE users; --` with no issue

Unfortunately, I don't quite remember how to do it with JS, but I advise against setting data with AJAX calls (JS disabled, NoScript, more clarity in the browser etc.)

Comment: I purposely avoided malicious injection in this case as the only person with access to this page (it's locked down pretty tight using other security methods) and the sole user of the page is my client (if they break it, they pay for it lol). Thanks for the suggestion anyway :) I know about SQL injection and this is the only data entry unprotected because I figured it's only going to be used by my client